# Can't set UINavigationControllerDelegate programatically (but can set via storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

(XCode 8.1, Swift 3.  Example in github at https://github.com/SuperTango/UINavigationControllerNoNavbar under the tags "byhand" and "storyboard")

I can set a UINavigationControllerDelegate by setting it up in a storyboard exactly as explained in the page http://blog.rinatkhanov.me/ios/transitions.html.  Here's an image:

[image: http://blog.rinatkhanov.me/assets/posts/transitions/delegate.png]

Here's a pic of how it looks for me:

[image]

This works great.

However, if I don't setup the delegate in the storyboard, but instead try to assign the same delegate programatically, the delegate methods aren't called.

```
    let delegate = JamNavigationControllerDelegate()
    NSLog(String(describing: delegate))
    navViewController.delegate = delegate
    navViewController.pushViewController(view3ViewController, animated: false)
    // and all subsequent push/pops don't use the delegate.
```

I put a test repo in github at https://github.com/SuperTango/UINavigationControllerNoNavbar.  There are two tags "byhand" and "storyboard" which should be self explanitory.

Any ideas?

Comment: The delegate methods don't get called because there is nothing holding a strong reference to the delegate so it gets deallocated at the end of whatever scope you are creating it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navViewController.delegate` is a `weak var`. This means that some other object must keep a strong reference to the delegate so that it stays alive. In your code snippet, `delegate` is only kept around until the end of that snippet (which I'm guessing is in a method). As soon as the snippet is over, the `delegate` var goes out of scope. The `navViewController` is the only other object with a reference to that variable, but it is a `weak` reference, which means it doesn't increase the retain count. So the retain count will be 0, the object will be deallocated, and `navViewController.delegate` will be `nil`. You will need to add a property to your view controller to keep a strong reference to the `JamNavigationControllerDelegate`, or make the view controller itself the delegate.